# Codeigniter "group_by" query isn´t working?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I´ve been trying this to work but seems isn´t going anywhere.

The problem is, the data doesn´t show in the View as a combobox it displays this error;

> A PHP Error was encountered  Severity: Notice Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$Campus Filename: views/energy_search_campus.php Line Number: 28  "  >c_name.

So dunno where the problem should be... in the model, view, controller or even the db. Thanks in advance.

**Model:**

```
function campus_finder()
{
    $this->db->group_by('campus');
    $this->db->order_by('faculty', 'asc');
    $query = $this->db->get('cpanel_energy');
    if($query->num_rows()>0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $services[$row->id] = $row;
        }
        return $services;
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="finder">
    <div>
        <label>Campus</label>
    </div>
    <select
            id="campus"
            name="campus"
            class="form-control"
        >
            <option value="">----</option>
        <?php foreach($catalogue as $item): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $item->Campus; ?>"
            <?php if($campus) echo ($item->campus==$campus)? 'selected' : ''; ?>
            ><?php echo $item->campus; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function campus_search()
{
    $submit = $this->input->post('send');
    $campus = $this->input->post('campus');
    $year = $this->input->post('year');
    if($submit=='goback')
    {
        redirect("energy/catalogue/");
    }
    else
    {
        $data['catalogue']  = $this->model_energy_consumption->campus_finder();
        $data['voucher']    = $this->model_energy_consumption->results_campus();
        $data['services']   = $this->modelo_energy_consumption->services_catalogue_campus();
        $data['campus'] = $campus;
        $data['year'] = $year;
```

**DB:**

```
MAINTENANCE_JOB_ITEMS
|----|---------|---------|--------|
| id | account | faculty | campus |
|----|---------|---------|--------|
  1    898946    f_name    c_name
```

Comment: Traduzindo o erro. O erro esta no teu view na pagina `energy_search_campus.php` na linha 28.  Ta falando que a propriedade `c_name` do objeto `$Campus` na esta definido.  Provalvamento a sua query esta retornando um objeto vazio, e vc esta tentando pegar a propriedade de um objeto que nao foi definido pq esta vazio.

Comment: Ohh nevermind... problem solved. Dammit I should pay more attention to the code... Minus/Mayus :(.

Answer (score 0):

In the model you are returned $services , but the values are saved in  $servicios variable

Comment: Error: <option value="<?php echo $item->Campus; ?>" Should be <option value="<?php echo $item->campus; ?>" Dude what a mistake! x_x

Answer (score 0):

first call select function to select some record then group them
like this :

```
$this->db->select('user_id, first_name,last_name');
```